# Getting the binding error in WCF. Cannot understand what it is.

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

```
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

 Source Error: 

  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.     Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

 Stack Trace: 


   [InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].]
```

System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +12366396
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress) +12363749
      System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection) +67
      System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration() +108
      System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +192
      System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +49
      System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +151
      System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +30
      System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +422
      System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1461
      System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +44
      System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +651

```
  [ServiceActivationException: The service '/BulkEmailService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +688590
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +190

     System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +359
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Here is my Web.config file. Please help.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>

     <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
     </system.web>
     <connectionStrings>
       <add name="WWDbConnect"
            connectionString="Data Source=(dev0320);USER ID = scott; Password = t;Max Pool Size=200;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
     </connectionStrings>
     <system.serviceModel>
       <bindings>
         <basicHttpBinding>
           <binding name="BasicHttpBindingWithNoSecurity" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000">
             <security mode="Transport">
               <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None"
                   realm="" />
               <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
             </security>
           </binding>
         </basicHttpBinding>
       </bindings>
       <client/>
       <services>
           <service name="WW.Common.Service.Impl.EmailService" behaviorConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingWithNoSecurity">
             <host>
               <baseAddresses>
                 <add baseAddress = "https://localhost:8270/Design_Time_Addresses/TestWcfEmailServiceLibrary/EmailService/" />
               </baseAddresses>
             </host>
             <endpoint address="EmailService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WW.Common.Service.Contract.IEmailService" />
             <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingWithNoSecurity" 
                       name="mexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
           </service>
         </services>
         <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
             <behavior name="EmailService">
               <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
               <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
               <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application"
                  suppressAuditFailure="true"
                  serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Success"
                  messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Success" />
           </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
       <diagnostics>
         <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                         maxMessagesToLog="3000"
                         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                         logMalformedMessages="false"
                         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
       </diagnostics>
       <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
     </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
     </system.webServer>

   </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using https in your base address, but your binding is basicHttpBinding. Looking at your config I am assuming you are planning to use certificates. I would recommend that you change your binding to WSHttpBinding

```
<endpoint address="test" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WW.Common.Service.Contract.IEmailService"/>
```

Alternately, if you want to use http only. change the base address to http as shown below. Note, I have also removed the binding configuration from your code

```
 <service name="WW.Common.Service.Impl.EmailService">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8270/Design_Time_Addresses/TestWcfEmailServiceLibrary/EmailService/" />
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="EmailService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WW.Common.Service.Contract.IEmailService" />
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                    name="mexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
```

I will also recommend that you read up on WCF bindings

Comment: I am new to WCF and so I just copied from another project. So I have no clue on how to use certificates :-( Now if I have to use a simple case how do I change the config file to make it work?

Comment: ok... are you trying to use certificates if not. change the base address to remove https. I will update my answer

Comment: Base address meaning changing https to http? I did that but even that is not working

Comment: Perfect. It worked. Thank you so much. Do you have any good article to read on WCF Bindings? There are so many that I am getting confused which one to read on.. If you have any Basic one that explains things clearly would help. Thank you.